# Questions on changing bounds of integration for double-integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

I'm having difficulty understanding how to properly change these bounds of integration. When I set up the bounds, which x or y bound is supposed to depend on the other?

$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{\cos(y)}7\cos(y) dxdy$$

I came up with below, but I believe my method was flawed or I misunderstood which operations need to be swapped in order to properly set each minimum and maximum. I feel that I may be mixing up general trigonometric rules with setting up bounds.

$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\int_{\arccos(0)}^{\arccos(x)}7\cos(y) dydx$$

Comment: are you sure the integrand is independent of $x$?

Comment: @CalvinKhor, I'm not sure - I suppose that is part of the question, I am having issues understanding dependencies when changing bounds.

Comment: You don't seem to understand my concern, if the integrand doesn't depend on $x$ then the integral wrt $x$, no matter how complicated in $y$, is trivial:

$$\int_{a(y)}^{b(y)} f(y) dx = f(y) \int_{a(y)}^{b(y)} dx = f(y)  (b(y) - a(y)) $$

Comment: Then in that case yes, it is independent of x. The problem is borrowed directly from my university's previous term final and it asks to change the bounds of integration and evaluate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When integrating a function $f(x,y)$,
$$\int_A^B\int_{C(y)}^{D(y)} f(x,y) dxdy$$
you can rewrite the integration region as
$$ \{(x,y): A\le y \le B , C(y) \le x \le D(y) \}$$
For reasonable functions $C,D$, this is equivalent to
$$ \{ (x,y) : \inf C \le x \le \sup D , D^{-1}(x)<y<C^{-1}(x)\}$$
which gets you
$$\int_{\inf C}^{\sup D} \int_{D^{-1}(x)}^{C^{-1}(x)} f(x,y) dydx$$

Comment: This clears a lot up, I'm beginning to understand the dependencies now. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

$\int_{0}^{\cos(y)}7\cos(y) dx= 7 \cos^2(y)$,

hence

$ \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{\cos(y)}7\cos(y) dxdy= 7 \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \cos^2(y) dy$.